# Django Admin Inlines with many fields, possible to have inline add button create popup?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've got 3 models:

```
class Top(models.Model):
    toptitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='top title')

class Middle(models.Model):
    top = models.ForeignKey(Top)
    middletitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='middle title')
    importantfield1 = models.TextField(verbose_name='important field 1')
    importantfield2 = models.TextField(verbose_name='important field 2')
    ...
    importantfield20 = models.TextField(verbose_name='important field 20')
```

Now when I'm viewing the Admin page for a Top, I want to see what Middles are related to it (and be able to add and edit Middles from this page or from a link on this page).

I can do that easily enough with inlines. The problem is it becomes unwieldy with so many (required) fields in Middle.

If I specify that the inline is only to show middletitle

```
class MiddleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MiddleInline
    fields = ('middletitle',)
    extra = 0
```

I've got two problems. The first is that there is no way for me to get to the page on which I can edit all of the fields for Middles that already exist (without having to go to the Admin menu, selecting Middle and having to find the right Middle there). The second problem is that if I try to add another Middle from this inline, it allows me to create a middle with just a middletitle, but leaving empty all of the required importantfields.

I've been able to deal with the first issue by adding a link to edit the object:

```
class MiddleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    def changeform_link(self,instance):
        if instance.id:
            changeform_url = reverse(
                'admin:myapp_middle_change', args=(instance.id,)
            )
            return '<a href="'+ changeform_url + '" target="_blank">Details</a>'
        return ''
    changeform_link.allow_tags = True
    changeform_link.short_description = ''   # omit column header

    model = MiddleInline
    fields = ('middletitle','changeform_link')
    extra = 0
```

but now I'm not sure how to deal with the second problem.

Ideally I'd like the 'Add Another Middle' section to open up a pop up for creating a new Middle (with the Top already set and having/requiring all of the importantfields), which when saved would refresh the inline.

Is there a way of doing this? Am I approaching this entirely wrong?

Comment: Four years after you asked this I find myself searching for solutions to the same problem. Please let me know if you sorted this out or abandoned it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640553/foreignkey-style-inlines-for-django-admin-scalability-issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I had somewhat the same issue. My solution was to display two different fieldsets for two different situations.

The `ModelAdmin` class has a `get_fieldsets(self,request, obj=None)` functions which i override in my `admin.py` file.

so something like:

```
class MiddleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    '''your stuff'''

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            fields = list(('''tuple of the fields you want to display if it's a new object'''))
        else:
            fields = list(('''tuple of the fields you want to display if it's not a new object'''))
        return [(None, {'fields': fields})]
```

I am not quite entirely sure I got your question right, but I hope this can help!